# AndEngine doesn't work on Motorola Defy

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I'm now testing an app I'm wokring on, on various devices and unfortunately a problem I'm encountering is that for some reason any AndEngine activity I tried to run on a Motorola Defy device with Android 2.2.2 doesn't work and crashes the app.

On the other devices I tested these AndEngine activities such as Samsung Galaxy S2 and Samsung Galaxy Mini everything worked flawlessly.

(I'm using AndEngine with GLES2)

The error I'm receiving is this

> 

```
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 21
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.opengl.vbo.attribute.VertexBufferObjectAttributeFix.glVertexAttribPointer(VertexBufferObjectAttributeFix.java:39)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.opengl.vbo.attribute.VertexBufferObjectAttributes.glVertexAttribPointers(VertexBufferObjectAttributes.java:50)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.opengl.shader.ShaderProgram.bind(ShaderProgram.java:126)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.opengl.shader.PositionColorTextureCoordinatesShaderProgram.bind(PositionColorTextureCoordinatesShaderProgram.java:89)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.opengl.vbo.VertexBufferObject.bind(VertexBufferObject.java:160)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite.preDraw(Sprite.java:170)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:1266)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:1072)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:1295)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedDraw(Scene.java:261)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:1072)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawScene(Engine.java:623)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:613)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:104)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1332)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318): Caused by: org.andengine.util.exception.AndEngineRuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library andengine not found
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.opengl.GLES20Fix.<clinit>(GLES20Fix.java:22)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     ... 16 more
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library andengine not found
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     at org.andengine.opengl.GLES20Fix.<clinit>(GLES20Fix.java:20)
06-02 13:46:12.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3318):     ... 16 more
```

To me it seems as there's a real problem with running AndEngine's infrastructure for some reason, and not like its a problem with my code.

Even the most simple andengine acitivities with just a single simple sprite crash.

I hope there's a reasonable solution to this problem.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As Nicolas suggested I debugged the AndEngine.isDeviceSupported method, and the exception was thrown on this line

> System.loadLibrary("andengine");

in this method

```
private static void checkCodePathSupport() throws DeviceNotSupportedException {
        if(SystemUtils.isAndroidVersionOrLower(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)) {
            try {
                System.loadLibrary("andengine");
            } catch (final UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
                throw new DeviceNotSupportedException(DeviceNotSupportedCause.CODEPATH_INCOMPLETE, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception is UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library andengine not found.

I hope this helps..

Comment: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/issues/32

Comment: Hey Samir, thanks for the link. Thought I couldn't understand from it if there's a solution or if its still unresolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to test it on a new Motorola Defy **Plus** with gingerbread version and it worked. So either the old android version was not supported (2.2) or the older regular Motorola Defy's hardware was not supported.

Answer (score 1):

As seen here: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/launcher/ExampleLauncher.java#L61

Call:

```
if(!AndEngine.isDeviceSupported()) {
    // Oh no
}
```

If that method doesn't exist in your code yet, update to the latest GLES2 revision.

Report back where exactly it fails.

Thanks. =)

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I added this code segment as you had suggested and indeed it returns false on the Motorola Defy. Do you have any idea why the Motorla Defy can't support AndEngine? It seems like it should be able to do so, it runs on Android 2.2.2, and its a device of a pretty mainstream firm (Motorola). Thanks!

Comment: I just now noticed you asked where exactly it fails. I would have to check it out later today, and I'll report back.

Comment: Hey again, I debugged the AndEngine code as you suggested, I updated my question with the new information.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the native libraries exist in the AndEngine project and are in the correct folder? Also are you properly using AndEngine as a Library Project?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, sorry for the long delay. I downloaded the AndEngine from the mercurial repository and compiled it as a library project without any modifications. I added the .jar file to my application's \libs directory and I referenced my project to that library. So I think that in this case I did everything allright. I think that the fact that this does work on other devices (Galaxy S2 for example) means that this is not the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You are using a repository that hasn't been updated since... a long time! Go here: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

Comment: Hey Nicholas! I'm terribly sorry! Apparently I'm very silly. I actually meant to say that I'm using source from the "GitHub repository" and not the Mercurial repository. So if I already use the github repository I believe I'm running with the latest code. That's why I'm also able to use the AndEngine.isDeviceSupported() method.